# RadGrid RadComboBox Client Popup Help

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, radgrid, radcombobox

Need some help figuring this one please. I would like to add an On RowClick Event handler to my RadGrid to handle the selections from RadComboBox in the RadGrid Editform mode. What I would like to do is to, when user makes a selection from the combobox, display a RadWindow to allow user make additional Selections to be  displayed in a textbox in the RadGrid Editform. SO far, what I have displays nothing, not even alertboxes

```
  function RowCreated(rowObject) {
       alert("Row with Index: " + rowObject.Index + " was created");
   }

   function RowSelected(sender, args) {
       alert("row selected");
       inputFieldValue = args.getDataKeyValue("Type");
       alert(inputFieldValue);
   }

   function RowClick(rowIndex, e) {
       alert("row Clicked");
       var sourceElement;
       alert(rowIndex);
   }
```

---

The attachment to the grid happens in the client events tag

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="securityGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"  AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Height="99.9%" AllowCustomPaging="true">
                              <MasterTableView ShowFooter="true"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" EnableViewState="true" ClientDataKeyNames="HKey" DataKeyNames="HKey">
                                    <NoRecordsTemplate>
                                        <div align="center" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; color: Green; width: 100%;">
                                            There Are No Records To Display. Please Select Another View.</div>
                                    </NoRecordsTemplate>
                                    <Columns>
                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="EHKey" Visible="false" DataField="EHKey" />
                                        <telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn UniqueName="Active" HeaderText="Active" DataField="Active"
                                            ColumnEditorID="ReportEditor">
                                            <ItemStyle Width="70" />
                                            <HeaderStyle Width="70" />
                                        </telerik:GridCheckBoxColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridDropDownColumn UniqueName="UILocation" DataSourceID="UILocation_DS"
                                            HeaderText="UI Location" DataField="UILocation" ListTextField="Description" ListValueField="PrimaryKey"
                                            DropDownControlType="RadComboBox" ColumnEditorID="ReportEditor">
                                            <ItemStyle Width="20%" Height="18" />
                                            <HeaderStyle Width="20%" />
                                        </telerik:GridDropDownColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridDropDownColumn UniqueName="Type" DataSourceID="SecurityType_DS" HeaderText="Type"
                                            DataField="SecurityType" ListTextField="Description" ListValueField="PrimaryKey"
                                            DropDownControlType="RadComboBox" ColumnEditorID="ReportEditor">
                                            <ItemStyle Width="120" Height="18" />
                                            <HeaderStyle Width="120" />
                                        </telerik:GridDropDownColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Item" HeaderText="Item" DataField="ItemList"
                                            ColumnEditorID="ReportEditor">
                                            <ItemStyle Width="10%" />
                                            <HeaderStyle Width="10%" />
                                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridDropDownColumn UniqueName="Access" DataSourceID="AccessType_DS" HeaderText="Access"
                                            DataField="AccessType" ListTextField="Description" ListValueField="PrimaryKey"
                                            DropDownControlType="RadComboBox" ColumnEditorID="ReportEditor">
                                            <ItemStyle Width="120" />
                                            <HeaderStyle Width="120" />
                                        </telerik:GridDropDownColumn>
                                        <%-- <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="ItemList" Visible="false" DataField="ItemList" />--%>
                                        <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn HeaderText="Edit" ButtonType="ImageButton" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn">
                                            <ItemStyle Width="40" CssClass="WATSImageButton" />
                                            <HeaderStyle Width="40" />
                                        </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                                        <telerik:GridButtonColumn UniqueName="DeleteCommandColumn" ButtonType="ImageButton"
                                            CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Del" ConfirmTitle="Delete Strategy Milestone!"
                                            ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to delete this record?" ConfirmDialogType="RadWindow"
                                            ConfirmDialogHeight="100" ConfirmDialogWidth="350">
                                            <ItemStyle Width="35" CssClass="WATSImageButton" />
                                            <HeaderStyle Width="35" />
                                        </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
                                    </Columns>
                                    <EditFormSettings>
                                        <FormMainTableStyle GridLines="None" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="0" Width="100%"
                                            CssClass="masterTable" />
                                        <FormTableStyle CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="0" Width="50%" />
                                        <FormStyle Width="100%" BackColor="#ffffe1"></FormStyle>
                                        <EditColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" CancelText="Cancel" UpdateText="Update" InsertText="Add" />
                                    </EditFormSettings>
                                </MasterTableView>
                                <ClientSettings>
                                    <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" />
                                        <ClientEvents OnRowClick="RowClick" OnGridCreated="GridCreated" />
                                    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="false" />
                                    <ClientEvents />
                                </ClientSettings>
                            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: How are you attaching the RowClick event?

Answer (score 0):

Debug your js code to see what part of it gets processed and whether errors occur. This can help you trace what's wrong.

Comment: Debugging by adding alerts in the code have not yielded much as it seems to run occassionally and not as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following line:

```
alert("Click on row instance: " + eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical());
```

You haven't defined eventArgs. This is the first line of the function so it makes sense that "nothing" happens when you click on the row.

Change your function to be as follows:

```
function RowClick(rowIndex, eventArgs) {
           alert("Click on row instance: " + eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical());
           var e = window.event;
           var sourceElement;
           alert(sourceElement);
           if (e.srcElement) {
               sourceElement = e.srcElement;
               alert("sourceElement");
           }
           else if (e.target) {
           sourceElement = e.target;
           alert("target");
           }

       alert("About to check ROw Index");
       if (rowIndex != null) {

           alert("Checked ROw Index");
           inputField = grid.MasterTableView.Rows[rowIndex].Control.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0];
           alert(inputField);
           selvalue = sourceElement.value;
           alert(selvalue);
           if (inputField != null) {
               alert("About to show it");
               var popuppage = "userroleselect.aspx" + "?sel=" + selvalue + "&avail=" + inputField.value;
               alert("Shown it!");
               window.radopen(popuppage, "UserRoleDialog");
           }
           else {
               alert("Did Not Make it");
           }
       }
   }
```

Notice the eventArgs parameter also notice the the variable e is now defined in the function.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part. Even though none of my alert boixes show up,the problem seems to be with the line inputField = grid.MasterTableView.Rows[rowIndex].Control.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0];

Comment: The first problem is that your alert boxes should be appearing.  I would begin commenting out unnecessary code and until the alert boxes appear.  Once they are appearing, I would add code one line at a time and then test after each line is added until the exact location of the problem is determined.

Comment: I cleared out all of the code and was not able still to get a popup

Comment: I ran a quick test using the example code from http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid_onrowclick.html and it worked perfectly.  I would need to see your "simple" RowClick function to see what is going on.  It is simple to wire up the onrowclick event of a GridView and you should be able to get an alert without any problems.

Comment: @Allison, above is what I have now

Comment: The next step is to remove columns from the RadGrid one at a time and test after each is removed.  Alternatively, try a test on a new page with just a default RadGrid bound to your data and attach the onrowclick handler and see what happens.